# How to use a variable from `read` as an argument to another program?

Tags: svn, shell, ubuntu

Here's my script:

```
read -p 'commit message: ' msg
svn status | grep ^\? | awk '{ print $2 }'  | egrep "\.(py|js|html|png|jpg)$" | xargs svn add
svn ci -m "$msg"
```

When I run it, however, I get this error:

```
mark@mark-ubuntu:~/myproject$ ./commit.sh 
commit message: test
svn: Try 'svn help' for more info
svn: Not enough arguments provided
```

I really don't know much about shell programming. Is the message not being passed to `svn ci` properly or what? How can I make it work?

---

```
mark@mark-ubuntu:~/myproject$ bash -x commit.sh 
+ read -p 'commit message: ' msg
commit message: hello world
+ egrep '\.(py|js|html|png|jpg)$'
+ xargs svn add
+ awk '{ print $2 }'
+ grep '^?'
+ svn status
svn: Try 'svn help' for more info
svn: Not enough arguments provided
+ svn ci -m 'hello world'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The svn ci line seems fine. You can try running it with bash -x to see where the error is:

```
$ bash -x commit.sh
```

Comment: Ah... didn't know about that. It appears the problem is that there's nothing to add as I've already ran this a few times. Is there a way to perhaps skip the `svn add` if they previous query doesn't find anything?

Comment: You can separate those lines into an if block based on the return code of svn status. $? always has the return code of the previous command.